# Drawing shapes on image at consistent size regardless of dimensions

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a program where I draw a bunch of custom shapes and objects on a canvas that sits on top of an image.

The images sizes vary hugely and they are stretched proportionally to fit the view.

When I draw the shapes, I also create some editing elements (frames and handles etc) for them so they can be scaled/rotated and the like.

The problem is that due to the differing dimensions/DPI of the images, these editing elements can either be massive or tiny depending on the image.

I have tried different methods like scaling the editing elements based on a scale factor calculated from the image sizes, but I'm not terribly happy with the result.

Can anyone suggest a good way to draw these editor elements at a consistent size regardless of the size of the image below it? As in a 1px or unit line will appear exactly the same on a 100 x 100 or 10000 x 10000 image?

I dabbled with adorners hoping they might be the solution, but they scale exactly the same as my custom shapes.

Any suggestions would be awesome, thank you!

Comment: Canvas on the bottom.  Draw the image on that canvas and scale it (the Image, not the canvas).  Draw the shapes next on the same canvas and they will not be affected by the image's scaling.

Comment: Thanks Joe I will try it. Would that mess with the coordinates in relation to the drawn elements and the image? I didn't mention on my post, but I save the locations of these drawn elements so they are loaded and positioned automatically on the image

Comment: Creates an Image of the specified size.
On top of it, overlay Canvas with the same dimensions.
Since the Image is always the same size, regardless of the size of the original image, the coordinates in the Canvas become actually relative proportional to the original image.